# What does the UPDATE config for the DynamoDBMapper imply?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-mapper

According to the DynamoDBMapper documentation in the AWS Java SDK, the **save** method of the DynamoDBMapper class, takes a config (of DynamoDBMapperConfig type) as one of the inputs.

In the documentation ([link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.html#save-T-com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBSaveExpression-com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperConfig-)) the following has been provided as the explanation for the UPDATE config.

> UPDATE (default) : UPDATE will not affect unmodeled attributes on a save operation and a null value for the modeled attribute will remove it from that item in DynamoDB. Because of the limitation of updateItem request, the implementation of UPDATE will send a putItem request when a key-only object is being saved, and it will send another updateItem request if the given key(s) already exists in the table.

I am unable to understand this. What does this config mean? Can someone explain it in simple terms?